# Rails - Rendering a Partial without having to use "_" in front of the filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I render a partial without having to supply the "_" in front of the file name?  Is there a parameter I can call to not use it?

This problem popped up using RABL and Backbone - using RABL requires me to have a file in my views like "index.json.rabl".  But, when I use embed the JSON right on the page load (as is usual with Backbone), I'm required to call the file "_index.json.rabl".  These 2 files are the exact same thing, just required to have different names.  I'm looking to use just 1 file, "index.json.rabl" and force the render() function to look for that file name, without the "_".

=> EDIT

The standard solutions that people have described below don't work.  It's likely a RABL issue then?  The below code *always* goes to the views/countries/_index.json.rabl file.

In my .erb file

```
countryList.reset(<%=get_json("countries", "index", @countries)%>);
```

In my application_helper.rb file

```
def get_json(view_path, view_action, object)
    path = view_path + '/' + view_action + ".json"
    return raw(render(path, object: object, :formats => [:rabl]))
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [RailsCast #322 on RABL](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl?view=asciicast):

```
<div id="articles" data-articles="<%= render(template: "articles/index.json.rabl") %>" >
```

Start from here, and then figure out what's wrong. But it's clear that `render template: path` is the syntax you want.

Comment: The code you've pasted from RailsCast doesn't work.  Literally pasted into my page, changing "articles" to "countries", still the same "Template is missing" error.

Comment: It's probably time that you create a vanilla rails App with a Rabl template implemented like Railscasts, and let us see the code for ourselves. Most answers here are telling you the same thing - it's likely that there's something in your app that's causing your problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can render a file by doing the following:

```
render :file => "filename"
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try `render :template => "file_name"` ?

Comment: that still defaults it to use the "_" in the views/layouts folder - throws an error if that file is not there

Comment: that can't be correct, check this chapter on `render` functionality: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Answer (score 0):

Ok try:

```
<%= render :file => 'views_directory/index' %>
```

Where `views_directory` is the name of your directory in the views 8)

OLD:

> If the content is the same use:
>
> ```
> render :partial => "index"
> ```
>
> in index.json.rabl and the content in _index.json.rabl

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having 2 files by creating a helper function I can call that will code around the need for "_".  Take my example x 50 for a large application, it'd be much easier to just have a simple helper method.

Comment: No, that doesn't work either.  It seems like it's a RABL specific problem now.  I will amend my post above to include the RABL code.